# what is the salary of a postdoc without PhD degree yet in netherlands

Tags: salary, netherlands

My PhD contract is about to end soon. I got a postdoc position in the Netherlands after that but I don't have the PhD degree yet. Which salary step will I get in scale 10?

Comment: The best solution would be to contact the university and directly ask them. The number may change due to individual circumstances (eg if you don't have the PhD yet), and also it is something they sure should know.

Comment: ... *My PhD contract is about to end soon* ... How much is left? Is the PhD defence done?

Answer (score 3):

You ask

> Which salary step will I get in scale 10?

Although the salary scale for the Collective Agreement of Dutch Universities (CAO) is *fixed*, the step (*trede*) a postdoc would be placed on scale 10 is not ***constant***.
It depends on numbers of factors: one is the [years of experience](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/63972/how-are-years-of-experience-counted-for-determining-level-on-salary-scale-for-a).
Though *fixed*, yet negotiable! ([more of the PI](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/23797/162770) though getting you on 'higher' steps).

Depending on where you are with the PhD and whether your PhD status will count or not, you might be looking at **10(3)** or **10(4)**.
Even at that, it's best to get clarity from the PI and/or HR. I'll rather go the route of '*negotiating*' with the PI.

Following might be worthwhile

- [In the Dutch salary system, how do the "steps" ("trede") work?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/138722/in-the-dutch-salary-system-how-do-the-steps-trede-work)
- [Salary, collective labour agreement](https://www.wur.nl/en/jobs/tailor-made-conditions-of-employment.htm)

Comment: In the case of the OP, 10(2) would not be implausible.

Answer (score 0):

Note that a postdoc position in general requires a PhD. If all you are missing is some bureaucratic paper work you should talk to them but probably this will have no effect on your salary and they will just pay you the same as if you already have the PhD.

If however your PhD still requires a few months of work and is not actually finished yet you need to carefully check whether the offer for a postdoc position is still valid at all. In that case you want a PhD student position and that is not the same as a postdoc position.